# Reading several XML files into an array and parsing them with Perl

Tags: xml, arrays, perl

I would like to read multiple XML files in an array and then parse them one by one.

Here is what I am doing:

```
my $output = "c:\documents\outputfiles";
opendir (FILE, $output) or die "can't open the $output";

my @files = readdir File;
print @files;
```

This will list all the files under "outputfiles" directory. How do I just read the XML files?

I also tried:

```
my @files = grep {*.xml} readdir FILE;
```

This does not work.

Comment: You cannot use backslashes for windows paths inside a double quoted string. Use either slashes or a single quoted string. You should also always `use warnings; use strict;`

Comment: By the way, that code will not compile or run properly, because of two major errors: The backslashes in the string, and the mismatched file handles `FILE` and `File`. You should never post code that you have not tried to run, because details are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grep takes either an expression or a block as its first parameter. Also consider using `autodie`:

```
use autodie;
my $path = './files';

opendir(DIR, $path);
my @files = grep { -f "$path/$_" && m/.xml$/ } readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

say for @files;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@files = glob("C:/documents/outputfiles/*.xml");
```

@files is list of all xml files.

EDIT: Inserted full path in glob function according to [TLP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp)'s comment.

Comment: `glob "C:/documents/outputfiles/*.xml"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a pattern to [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) like this:

```
my @files = grep {/\.xml$/i} readdir FILE;
```

Comment: Should perhaps use `/i` modifier to ignore case.